# Dectecting Umlauts in Powershell with -eq or -ne

Tags: powershell, unicode, diacritics

I am simply trying to detect Domänen-Benutzer in my powershell script so I can ignore it.

I figured I can simply run a not equals if statement so I can ignore it. However this not working. I can detect everything else with this statement but I am pretty sure it is the ä that is screwing me over. I have had issues previosuly with powershell and umlauts. I can't figure out how to get the -eq or -ne statement to accept encoding though.

Simple Code:

```
 $groups = Get-Content "EntferntGruppen.txt" -Encoding UTF8
$string = "Domänen-Benutzer"
foreach ($group in $groups){
    if ($group -eq $string) {
        $group
      }else{
          "nah"
      }
}
```

I would like to add I have tried `-Encoding Unicode, UTF7, UTF32, Default` I have also originally didn't bother with the $string variable and simply had `if($group -eq "Domänen-Benutzer")` which also failed.

If someone could educate me on how to deal with umlauts that would be great!

At the request of @Olaf here are some inputs from the EntferntGruppen.txt, these are generated on the fly from an AD user.

```
Domänen-Benutzer
gl_SekretariatDUS
gl_ZeusUser
gl_LexwareUserSXF
gl_WEST_InternetUser
JederDUS
```

Comment: You may share a few sanitized but still representative lines of your input data source `EntferntGruppen.txt`  - formatted as code as well please. For me your code is working just as expected.

Comment: Edited in for you

Comment: @olaf could it be that I am running this account in English? Should I switch and use a German account perhaps? Also running Powersherll 5.1.17763.1007

Comment: At least I'm running this on a German culture setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unicode 0x00E4 code here:

```
$string = "Dom$([char]0x00E4)nen-Benutzer"
```

Comment: Is there a chart of those?